# How to get xml file from drawable folder Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have an xml file on a web page http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml on my application I use

```
static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
```

works fine but know I have put this file in my Android resource folder. So how do I get my file from android drawable folder like this `R.drawble.music.xml` instead of web page.
http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml

Comment: Why would you think you have to put it in the `drawable` folder? Is your music playlist a _drawable_?

Comment: I said i wont to get xml from android drawable folder instead of webpage

Comment: Then why would you thought it should be in the `drawable` folder to begin with? Is it a _drawable_?

Comment: it is a folder in android if you do not understand android dont wast time.

Comment: I understand _Android_ quite fine sir, there are different subfolders at the `res` folder, each of them for a specific purpose. The `drawable` folder is used to contain _drawables_, then you have other folders like `xml` to contain _xml_ files or `raw` to contain any kind of file that you want to preserve as is (as opposed to have the package builder mess with your file since it assumes its a drawable when its not)

Comment: man can you tell me how to retrive my xml file from that folder

Comment: No sir, there is no guarantee your file will even be in that folder in the generated apk, or if it is whether it will be intact or modified by the apk generation. You are not supposed to put things other than _drawables_ in the `drawable` folder. That's why I keep asking why do you want to put it there, because if you have a reason for it then you simply can't do it (at least not guaranteed to work). If you don't have a reason, then you should simply put it in a folder that matches your content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the xml into `/res/raw` folder.

Then use :

```
InputStream is=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_xml);
```

Then use this parser [XML PULL PARSER](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)

```
XmlPullParser xpp=XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
xpp.setInput(is,"your-encoding");
```

Thanks.

Comment: thanks man just one last thing how to use your coding replacing this one 
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String file = "res/drawable/music.xml";
XmlResourceParser parser = getContext().getAssets().openXmlResourceParser(file);
```

or in Kotlin:

```
val file = "res/drawable/music.xml"
val parser = context.assets.openXmlResourceParser(file)
```

It worked for me. And then you can look for examples of `XmlPullParser` to know how to use it.